# "Addition" of two classes

Tags: c++, oop, abstract-class, physics

I've been doing some dynamical system simulations in a rather crude functional way and am currently trying to figure out what can cpp objects bring to my code. More specifically, I was thinking about the following construction:

I would like to specify the dynamical system by an abstract class, say "DynSys", with a purely virtual method specifying the dynamics (say "energy" and others). Once I derive two concrete classes from DynSys, I would like to do a "superposition" of their instances in the sense of creation of a new DynSys object that returns an addition of the two respective dynamical member functions. Is this possible? E.G.:

```
DynamicHole Blackhole;     // DynSys derived
DynamicDisc Disc;          // DynSys as well
vector state;              // eg a dynamical array of numbers
Blackhole.energy(state);   // returns A(state)
Disc.energy(state);        // returns B(state)
??class?? HoleDisc = DynamicAddition(&Blackhole,&Disc); // is a DynSys
HoleDisc.energy(state);    // returns A(state)+B(state)
```

The pointer to a DynSys object is passed to the simulation itself, so it is important for the result to be a DynSys object.

I saw some constructions using the "+" operator or befriending to add the *parameters* of the class. However, the problem here seems to be the fact that the addition process involving method addition would need to define a completely new concrete class.

I see a rather inelegant workaround by defining the "core" functions A(state,parameters), B(state,parameters) separately and then defining the superposition class by hand. I have quite a lot of superpositions to make, so I wondered whether there was a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, when you "add" to DynSys together you want to create some aggregation. Here is a pseudocode that could be adapted to your needs:

```
class DynSysGroup : public DynSys
{
    DynSys& m_a;
    DynSys& m_b;

public:
    DynSysGroup(DynSys& a, DynSys& b) : m_a(a), m_b(b) { }


    // I'm guessing the signature of energy()...
    void energy(vector& v)
    {
        // Get A(state) with m_a
        // Get B(state) with m_b
        // Do A(state) + B(state)
    }
}
```

And your line above

```
??class?? HoleDisc = DynamicAddition(&Blackhole,&Disc); // is a DynSys
```

would become

```
DynSysGroup HoleDisc(Blackhole, Disc);
```

Of course, with reference like `m_a` and `m_b` you need to make sure you don't get dangling reference. Maybe you'll need to use smart pointers like `std::shared_ptr`.

---

Side note: you may want to look into [`std::valarray`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray) and change the way `energy()` works: instead of taking a vector as parameter, you could simply return it (it if fits your design, of course).

```
std::valarray DynSys::energy() const { return ...; }
```

Comment: A more general approach would be to hold a vector of DynSys objects and not just m_a and m_b, and then addition and subtraction between groups can alo be performed in the same manner, but the idea remains the same.